# Does javax.jms.ExceptionListener delay the onException callback when network connection goes down?

Tags: networking, websphere, onexception

I'm using Websphere Application Server (WAS) 6.1's default messaging provider for JMS. My remote client application creates a connection, then does a `setExceptionListener` to register the callback.

When I simply stop the messaging engine using the WAS Integrated Solutions Console, my app behaves as expected, i.e., `onException` is called immediately and my app reacts accordingly. However, when I pull the network cable, the `onException` callback does not get called back for somewhere between 30 and 60 seconds.

The ugly result is that my app just tries to keep sending messages to WAS during this 30 to 60 second time frame and those messages just get lost. I've done several searches trying to find out more about the `ExceptionListener` (e.g., is there some configuration parameter used to specify a callback timeout), but have not had any success.

Hopefully, this makes sense to someone out there. Any suggestions how I might be able to detect the cable "cut" scenario more quickly? Thanks for your help.

-Kris

Answer (score 1):

You don't happen to have a 30 second TCP timeout defined?
If so, then MQ has handed over its responsibility temporarily to the JVM/OS and is waiting for for it to ACK with whatever network related operation it has requested. Perhaps try lowering the TCP timeout value...